# "this" won't refer to the div in a JQuery listener

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-waypoints

I have the below listener for a class `.my-class` (I'm using the waypoint plugin). However, if I try to call `$(this).addClass("hello")`, it does not add the class to the individual `div` that has the class and fired the listener.

On the other hand, if I call `$(".my-class").addClass("hello")` inside the function instead, it adds the class `hello` to ALL instances of `.my-class`, which is not what I want.

Am I misinterpreting how `this` is supposed to be used (I'm new to JS)? Shouldn't it refer to the single `div` that fires the listener and therefore add the class to that div?

```
$(".my-class").waypoint(function(e) {
    $(this).addClass("hello");
})
```

Comment: I'm not sure. Could you try posting a JSFiddle?

Comment: Try a `console.log($(this))` to see exactly what `$(this)` is. It may be a little hard to read, but should still help.

Comment: jQuery's standard is to execute fallback functions with the element in question as the `this` context. However, `.waypoint()` is from plugin code, not jQuery core code, so they may not be following this convention. The `this` context is going to be whatever the plugin set it to.

Comment: try this $(e.target).addClass("hello"); because I think this refers to to waypoint object

Comment: @Alexandar, yep. `e.target` didn't work, but `this.element` did, as suggested below. I wasn't aware what `this` refers to could change like that, thank you!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When using `waypoint`, `this` refers to the waypoint object. The waypoint object's element is the current div. So you would want to use

```
$(".my-class").waypoint(function(e) {
 $(this.element).addClass("hello");
})
```

Comment: @uj- - There is a guide to using the jQuery extension here too if you are interested: http://imakewebthings.com/waypoints/guides/jquery-zepto/

Comment: Thanks, I'll have a look.

Answer (score 0):

From the api docs, they have a snippet like this:

```
var waypoints = $('#options-only').waypoint({
  handler: function(direction) {
    notify(this.element.id + ' hit')
  }
})
```

so you might need to do $(this.element), or maybe this.element is already a jquery object? I don't know much about waypoint.